# User Summary/Recent Page - Date Range Options

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, recent-activity

When you go to your recent page, example for me:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/13249
```

You get a date range for the past few hours, like this:

```
?startdate=2010-05-19%2000:00:00z&enddate=2010-05-19%2023:59:59z&tab=summary
```

However, refreshing this page later or the next day, etc is counter-intuitive...it would be nice if there was a "today" option that translated to something like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/13249?date=today&tab=summary
//or...
http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/13249?day=0&tab=summary
//or another idea from someone smarter :)
```

In the second example day `0` would be today, `-1` yesterday, etc.  Alternatively, it could have 2 parameters, allowing `startdate` and `enddate` to either be integers or dates, integers being relative days...or something else entirely, but a relative option of some sort would be useful.

This would allow refreshing, additionally I think clicking on "today" should take you to this relative links that's *actually* today...since currently clicking "today" on a page you left up last night doesn't really do what you'd expect, it loads a new page with "yesterday" highlighted.

### Update: Second Related Issue

---

At certain times of the day, it seems that the *default* date range is not very useful, for example around **2PM EST (18:00 GMT)** the Summary page (`http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/{id}`, no params, e.g. mail icon link) becomes (by default) empty. For example, right now I have this range and current time:

- **Range:** `2010-05-20 18:04:27Z` to `2010-05-20 23:59:59Z`
- **Current Time:** `2010-05-20 18:09:23Z`

I think the default range algorithm needs a tweak, showing the last 5 minutes isn't very useful :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25681/url-to-recent-activity-page-accepts-full-timestamp-for-startdate-but-not-for-endd

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as we now break this down by day, let you link to any page, and highlight changes as they happen in real-time, calling this one [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).