# Why is the /user/recent/# link redirecting to a link with the date range fixed?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed

I'm not sure what happened but up until recently the user/recent page *seemed* to get the most recent stuff by just refreshing. Now the first time the page loads, it gets a 302 redirect that adds in some params that lock in the date.

This might be the same issue as [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50561/user-summary-recent-page-date-range-options) But that one is old enough that I'd think I would have spotted it well before now.

Whatever the case, the way it is now is *just flat broken* for anyone who wants to use tabbed browsing effectively.

Comment: It is most likely related to some tangential complaints about the timestamp of the recent envelope being inaccurate. The new update causes it to clear off any responses pretty much immediately after you have read them. I'm not sure how I feel about this.

Comment: It also causes Chrome's recent history conveniences to become less useful for SO. I dislike the change.

Comment: BTW: end date accepts dates in the future so for 90 days at a stretch you can avoid this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reverted; sorry for the pain.